# Create multiple-hop ssh connection without tcp forwarding

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I would like to login to another server via ssh via a jump sever. I would like to run system tests on the sever and receive their evaluation / result. The whole thing should take place automatically and I don't want to have to copy the individual test files to the target system.

```
  my_compuer --SSH--> Jump_Server --SSH--> Server(run system tests)
```

For security reasons, tcp forwarding is disabled in the sshd config of the jump server.
A dedicated username and a public key are required for both ssh connections.

The establishment of an SSH tunnel does not work due to the missing tcp forwarding. Here I get the error message "channel 1: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed". When I active tcp forwarding the ssh connection is working as expected.

Would ssh proxy represent a possibility to enable an ssh connection with deactivated tcp forwarding? Which additional authorizations would be required here on the jump server?

What furhter options would I have?

Comment: You could check [How to ssh forwarding with AllowTcpForwarding set to no?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406695/how-to-ssh-forwarding-with-allowtcpforwarding-set-to-no)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ssh hop for example

```
ssh -P 22 -J john@192.168.66.137:22 john@192.168.66.124:22
```